# C++ Inheritance and Virtual function error in simple program implementation

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, abstract

I am learning C++ and I am trying to implement a simple c++ program to create a abstract class as below:
Please explain why i am getting this error after compile? Please explain in simple language i am not a pro with terminologies and still learning OOPS concepts. Thank You in advance (code and error below)

### CODE:

```
/*
 * shape.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Mar 9, 2014
 *      Author: Drix
*/


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class shape{
public:
virtual void Draw(void)=0;
};


class circle:public shape{
public:
void Draw(double radius){
    radii = radius;
    cout << "The radius of the circle is "  << radii<<endl;
}
private:
double radii;
};

class square:public shape{
public:
void Draw(double side){
    s = side;
    cout << "The length of side of sqare is "  << s<<endl;
}
private:
double s;
};


int main(){

cout <<"Welcome to shape drwaing program"<<endl;
cout <<"Enter 1 to draw a sqare or 2 to draw a circle"<<endl;
int input;

cin>>input;
if(input == 1)
{
    cout << "Please enter the radius of the circle: ";
    double radius;
    cin >> radius;
    circle *p = new circle;
    p->Draw(radius);
}
if(input == 2)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the length of the side of a square: ";
        double side;
        cin >> side;
        square *t = new square;
        t->Draw(side);
    }
 }
```

### ERROR:

```
10:58:15 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Shape ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o shape.o "..\\shape.cpp" 
..\shape.cpp: In function 'int main()':
..\shape.cpp:51:19: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'circle'
..\shape.cpp:18:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'circle':
..\shape.cpp:14:15: note:   virtual void shape::Draw()
..\shape.cpp:59:20: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'square'
..\shape.cpp:28:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'square':
..\shape.cpp:14:15: note:   virtual void shape::Draw()

10:58:16 Build Finished (took 884ms)
```

Comment: In a nutshell, `void Draw(void)` is not the same as `void Draw(double)`, so you are not overriding the base class pure virtual method. There are plenty of duplicates out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the following: in the class `shape` you declared draw as taking no parameter:

```
virtual void Draw(void)=0;
```

whereas the subclass `circle` and `square` has `draw` expecting a double:

```
void Draw(double radius)
```

In `circle`, I think `radius` (together with probably something like center) should be passed to the constructor and draw should accept nothing. For example:

```
class circle:public shape{
private:
    double radii;
public:
    circle(double radius) radii(radius) {};
    void Draw(){
        cout << "The radius of the circle is "  << radii<<endl;
    }
};
```

Then you use it as

```
circle *p = new circle(radius);
p->Draw();
```

Or if you don't need dynamic allocation:

```
circle c(radius);
c.Draw()
```

Of course class `square` has the same problem.

Comment: Thank You , I find this optimization very helpful `circle *p = new circle(radius);`  single line .Also yes i could probably pass arguments to the constructor instead.

Answer (score 1):

The argument of the Draw method doesn't match.

in shape:

```
virtual void Draw(void)=0;
```

while in circle and square:

```
void Draw(double radius)
```

If you want to have  virtual method the arguments must match.

Comment: Ahh! Thank You ..  Follow up Question : is there any way to override this behavior?  meaning virtual function in Shape(base class) arguments having no type but derived classes being able to pass any type of argument double or char or int.

Answer (score 0):

This method in Shape should be (do not need the void)

```
class shape{ 
public: 
    virtual void Draw()=0;
};
```

When you declare Circle you need a `Draw` method (i.e one without the radius bit)